# CsvReader.ColumnCount always returns 0, different from CsvReader.Parser.Count

Tags: c#, csvhelper

Consider the following code:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(@"Title,Something");
sb.AppendLine();
sb.Append(@"hello world,abc");
sb.AppendLine();


using var stringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
using var csvReader = new CsvReader(stringReader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

int lineIndex = 0;

while (csvReader.Read())
{
    if (lineIndex == 0)
    {
        csvReader.ReadHeader();
        Debug.WriteLine($"header column count: {csvReader.ColumnCount} and {csvReader.Parser.Count}");
    }
    else
    {
        var foo = csvReader.GetRecord<Foo>();
        Debug.WriteLine($"data column count: {csvReader.ColumnCount} and {csvReader.Parser.Count}");

    }

    lineIndex++;
}

class Foo
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Something { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

This outputs:

```
header column count: 0 and 2
data column count: 0 and 2
```

I am confused about the both zeros, respectively `csvReader.ColumnCount` returning 0. Anyone can explain why? The documentation states "This should match IParser.Count". Well, should, but does not - but why? Using latest stable CsvHelper 30.0.1.

Comment: Issue Exists : [CsvReader.ColumnCount is not set](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1779) and an open PR [https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/pull/2163](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/pull/2163)

Comment: ^^ So, I guess you need to wait for the PR to be merged, use the workaround (Parser.Count), or find a different solution that works for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently you have to set `DetectColumnCountChanges = true` on `CsvConfiguration` in order to get the correct count from `csvReader.ColumnCount`.

```cs
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.AppendLine(@"Title,Something");
sb.AppendLine(@"hello world,abc");

var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture){
    DetectColumnCountChanges = true
};

using var stringReader = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
using var csvReader = new CsvReader(stringReader, config);

int lineIndex = 0;

while (csvReader.Read())
{
    if (lineIndex == 0)
    {
        csvReader.ReadHeader();
        Debug.WriteLine($"header column count: {csvReader.ColumnCount} and {csvReader.Parser.Count}");
    }
    else
    {
        var foo = csvReader.GetRecord<Foo>();
        Debug.WriteLine($"data column count: {csvReader.ColumnCount} and {csvReader.Parser.Count}");

    }

    lineIndex++;
}

class Foo
{
    public string Title { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Something { get; set; } = null!;
}
```